# How do you ensure that a distributed app is working as expected?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, workflow, distributed-computing, orchestration

Imagine a very simple user creation flow in an online marketplace:

- Service A (user service) receives the request and creates a user object and sends an async request to service B and C (e.g. via Kafka)
- Service B (notification service) receives the request and sends an email to the newly created user
- Service C (referral service) receives the request and credits some funds to the referrer

While this design might be laid out correctly in a design doc, it is only implicitly defined in code because the services talk to each other. How would you:

- Ensure that the services are talking to each other in the correct order when implementing the user creation flow (integration tests might not suffice here since they generally test a very narrow set of path)?
- Define and enforce SLO guarantees between services in production?
- Debug which service is to blame when the flow breaks down?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question. And I think this scenario is a great fit for considering an orchestrator. A Microservices Orchestrator platform such as [Netflix Conductor](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor) is designed to handle exactly these kind of scenarios.

With Conductor we can de-couple the flow and dependencies from the underlying functions itself and functions can be designed to do one simple thing such as saving user, notifying via email, credit referrals etc. We can then use the orchestration engine to assemble the required flow.

Such flows are executed really fast and the cost of latency is easily offset with the benefits you get.

1. Flow is defined as a workflow (this means the order can be controlled using the definition)
2. SLO guarantees - you can monitor for execution delays, failed transactions and retry and replay them as required. Latency required by an orchestrator is negligible
3. Debugging - with Conductor you'll get a UI that you can load up each transaction and look at what happened, which server executed it etc.

To explain these concepts better - I defined your use case here using some dummy APIs (this is a sandbox environment for Netflix Conductor)-

https://play.orkes.io/workflowDef/simple_user_creation_flow

And you can see an execution of this definition here:

https://play.orkes.io/execution/5095b5ef-3e2d-11ed-9d7b-1a5314838fe6

(For clarity - I work at https://orkes.io which offers a managed service for Netflix Conductor)